# What 016 017 in bash prompt, how can I make it correct in Terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, prompt

I saw a beautiful bash prompt [here](http://www.maketecheasier.com/8-useful-and-interesting-bash-prompts)

```
PS1="\n\[\e[30;1m\]\[\016\]l\[\017\](\[\e[34;1m\]\u@\h\[\e[30;1m\])-(\[\e[34;1m\]\j\[\e[30;1m\])-(\[\e[34;1m\]\@ \d\[\e[30;1m\])->\[\e[30;1m\]\n\[\016\]m\[\017\]-(\[\[\e[32;1m\]\w\[\e[30;1m\])-(\[\e[32;1m\]\$(/bin/ls -1 | /usr/bin/wc -l | /bin/sed 's: ::g') files, \$(/bin/ls -lah | /bin/grep -m 1 total | /bin/sed 's/total //')b\[\e[30;1m\])--> \[\e[0m\]"
```

It should looks like:

[image: Example]

After I added in my `.bashrc`, I found `\[\016\]l\[\017\]` and `\[\016\]m\[\017\]` doesn't correct in my terminal (for both `gnome-terminal` and `konsole`):
[image: My prompt1]

I found it works fine by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd>.

How can I make `\[\016\]l\[\017\]` and `\[\016\]m\[\017\]` works in my x-terminal?

---

My Investigation and environment:

- `016`/`017` in ASCII are: `SO  (shift out)` and `SI  (shift in)`
- My environment: Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: What a nice game of "spot the difference"

Comment: well... sorry for that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Bashish theme howto](http://bashish.sourceforge.net/doc/howto.html) says Shift Out "invokes the G1 (alternate) character set". I'm not sure, but it seems like your terminal either does not support that or the font you're using has no alternate character set.

[About the 'alternate linedrawing character set'](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/alternate_charset/) has a lot more details about this seemingly rather complex issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I've found the way to set the 'alternate linedrawing chars' in Pormpt: change `\[\016\]` to `\[\033(0\]`, and `\[\017\]` to `\[\033(B\]`. And it works!