# The Linux Prompt (PS1) doesn't show correctly in PuTTy (Line Drawing with Shift Out/Shift In)

Tags: command-line, putty

My [Linux Prompt](https://github.com/Marslo/LinuxStuff/blob/master/Configs/HOME/.marslo/.common_marslo#L77) set as:

```
┌─ (USERNAME@HOSTNAME PATH) ->
└─ $
```

The `PS1` is:

```
export PS1="\n\[\033[30;1m\]\[\033(0\]l\[\033(B\]\[\033(0\]q\[\033(B\] (\u@\h \[\033[31;1m\]\w\[\033[30;1m\]) ->\n\[\033(0\]m\[\033(B\]\[\033(0\]q\[\033(B\] \`if [ \$? = 0 ]; then echo \[\e[1\;30m\]\\$\[\e[1m\]; else echo \[\e[1\;31m\]\\$\[\e[0m\]; fi\` \[\033[0m\]"
```

Somehow, it **CANNOT** be shows correctly from PuTTy, screenshot is:
[image: difference]

The settings of [**Window** -> **Translation**](http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-linedraw) in My Putty:

- **Remote character set:** -> `UTF-8`
- **Handing of line drawing characters:** -> `Use Unicode line drawing code points`

How can I show the correct prompt in My PuTTy? (By the way, I tried all options of **Handing of line drawing characters:**)

---

#### PuTTy Prompt still cannot work by using:

```
if [ -z "$DISPLAY" ]
then
export PS1="\n\[\033[30;1m\]┌─ (\u@\h \[\033[31;1m\]\w\[\033[30;1m\]) ->\n└─ \`if [ \$? = 0 ]; then echo \[\e[1\;30m\]\\$\[\e[1m\]; else echo \[\e[1\;31m\]\\$\[\e[0m\]; fi\` \[\033[0m\]"
else
export PS1="\n\[\033[30;1m\]\[\033(0\]l\[\033(B\]\[\033(0\]q\[\033(B\] (\u@\h \[\033[31;1m\]\w\[\033[30;1m\]) ->\n\[\033(0\]m\[\033(B\]\[\033(0\]q\[\033(B\] \`if [ \$? = 0 ]; then echo \[\e[1\;30m\]\\$\[\e[1m\]; else echo \[\e[1\;31m\]\\$\[\e[0m\]; fi\` \[\033[0m\]"
fi
```

[image: new_ps1]

Comment: Also try [KiTTY](http://www.9bis.net/kitty/). The solution presented below works perfectly fine for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to fix this is to stop using "shift out/shift in" sequences, and start including the line-drawing characters directly as UTF-8 (just like you did in your example):

```
PS1="\n\[\033[30;1m\]┌─ (\u@\h \[\033[31;1m\]\w\[\033[30;1m\]) ->\n└─ \`if [ \$? = 0 ]; then echo \[\e[1\;30m\]\\$\[\e[1m\]; else echo \[\e[1\;31m\]\\$\[\e[0m\]; fi\` \[\033[0m\]"
```

The problem here is that PuTTY currently does not support the ISO 2022 alternate character set sequences when it's running in UTF-8 mode. There is a PuTTY [wishlist entry](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/utf8-plus-vt100.html) for this, along with explanation [why mixing UTF-8 and ISO 2022 is undesirable.](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html#term)

---

As in the comments: Note that older versions of Consolas did not have box-drawing characters. You'll have to obtain Consolas from Windows 8.

Comment: WoW, looks cool, I will let you know the result after tried. By te way, I using **Gnome-Terminal** and **PuTTy**. **How can I know the terminal is PuTTy or Gnome-Terminal**? So that I can add the `if...else...` for `PS1`

Comment: By the way, I'm using [`\`sudo fgconsole\` -gt 6`](https://github.com/Marslo/LinuxStuff/blob/54f6f6e99d1eca2025be438e4eab73502366ac71/Configs/HOME/.marslo/.common_marslo#L75) to find the Terminal is x-windows or not.

Comment: @Marslo: Don't bother – just use UTF-8 in both cases. GNOME Terminal has supported UTF-8 for many years...

Comment: @Marslo: Generally, such checks should be more specific. That is, think for a moment **why** you're checking for it. // Does the setting depend on X11? Then check if `$DISPLAY` is set; _do not_ use fgconsole, it'll fail on systems where you don't have root, it'll fail when your display manager decides to start Xorg on vt1 or vt2, or when VTs disappear from Linux, or when you're in a rescue shell on tty9... // Does it depend on a function that PuTTY has but GNOME Terminal hasn't? Try again; the same UTF-8 actually works fine in both, so skipping the check would make things simpler.

Comment: I've asked [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/743889/what-016-017-in-bash-prompt-how-can-i-make-it-correct-in-terminal) before because of the **PS1** doesn't show correctly. And, I got the answer [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=100705). Anyway, I think `$DISPLAY` is great. I will try it later.

Comment: Oh Yeah. [Your idea](https://github.com/Marslo/LinuxStuff/blob/master/Configs/HOME/.marslo/.common_marslo#L73) works in both my x-windows terminal (**Ctrl** + **Alt** + **F7**) and non-x-windows terminal (**Ctrl** + **Alt** + **F1** - **F6**). I will try it for PuTTy later.

Comment: Hi @grawity: `┌─' and `└─` cannot works for PuTTy. That's pity.... I've upload the latest screenshot to my question. You can check that. This is the full-screenhost: http://i.stack.imgur.com/rujiS.png

Comment: Ah, interesting. It's probably just missing in your font, then? Older versions of Consolas did not have it.

Comment: What should I say? Why are you know so much tips?!!!! Did you met these strange problem before too? I just want to say **It works now** by changed the font to `Lucida Console` !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! And, thank you soooooooo bloody much!!

Comment: If you can find a computer with Windows 8.1 or 8.0, its version of Consolas will have all box-drawing characters, so you could copy it to XP or Vista.